# Meteor.js MS:SEO results in 'Title of your home site' being set as title

Tags: meteor

Configuring SEO with Meteor.js results in 2 page titles for the home/root page.
When I first load the site it shows "Title of your home site".
When navigating through iron-router to home it shows "Home".
This is the guide i'm using [manuel-schoebel](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo)
There seems to be a issue logged for this [Github](https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo/issues/39)
Is this a issue with the code or a issue with the seo package?

**Router.coffee**

```coffee
Router.map ->
  @route "home",
    path: "/",
    onAfterAction: ->
      return  unless Meteor.isClient
      SEO.set
        title: "Home"
        meta:
          description: "Home description"

  @route "about",
    path: "/about",
    onAfterAction: ->
      return  unless Meteor.isClient
      SEO.set
        title: "About"
        meta:
          description: "About description"
```

**seo.coffee**

```coffee
SeoCollection.insert
  route_name: "home" # the name of the Iron-Router route
  title: "Title of your home site"
  meta: [ description: "This is the description of the document" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the SeoCollection.insert and replaced it the code bellow.
I also had to delete the SEO document in Mongo Database.
Working as expected now.

```coffee
Meteor.startup ->
  if Meteor.isClient
    SEO.config
      title: "Website Name"
      meta:
        description: "Description"
```